# External jquery theme with css is not loading

Tags: jquery, css

on my site on this link:
http://dualda.com/index.php?option=com_findme&view=register&lang=de

before was loading the jquery theme quite well. The Problem is only in the form part(adminform)- but somehow now it is not loaded any more. I can not find the error.

Normally it is using the "pfbc3" Class wich should load "Bootstrap - a front-end framework from Twitter"

Could you give me hint where the error could be?

Comment: What do you expect from that stylesheet ? It has no rule about styling form (selecti, input, textarea, ...).

Comment: not sure if it is related, but there is an error when initializing `SqueezeBox` in ln112 of modal.js . It uses `$` and no `adopt` method was found, but it would work if it was `$$`. It could be this or just bad timing, e.g. missing element, not right place of call etc, however you could try to replace the call of `SqueezeBox.initialize({})` with something like `(function($){SqueezeBox.initialize({});})($$);`